# SQL hard query: events between other events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables (simplified version):

levelsloaded:

- id (Int, Primary Key, Auto increment)
- globalId (Int, Key)
- date (Datetime, Key)
- serverId (Int, Key)
- gamemodeId (Int, Key)
- mapId (Int, Key)

playerjoins:

- id (Int, Primary Key, Auto increment)
- globalId (Int, Key)
- date (Datetime, Key)
- serverId (Int, Key)
- playerId (Int, Key)

playerleaves:

- id (Int, Primary Key, Auto increment)
- globalId (Int, Key)
- date (Datetime, Key)
- serverId (Int, Key)
- playerId (Int, Key)

I have thought for a few hours about this query already, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I want this: **Select all rows from levelsloaded where the level has been loaded on a moment where the player was playing on the server.**

I have tried to refine the "question", but that would make it unclear.

An example picture here:

[image: Example]

You see various level loaded events:

- The one on `16:22:57` is wanted, as it has happened after I have joined the server (and before I have left the server)
- The ones on `15:51:29` and `15:37:10` should not happen, as I was not playing on the server.

I know that this query is definately possibly, however I do not think it is a trivial query.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Also suggestions to solve it myself are much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I've managed to refine the query a little bit. FIrst step to obtaining the solution would be to: Create a subquery that gets gets every level load between a player join and a player leave, only how to get that? Consider the following table of events:

- map 1 loads
- player A joins
- map 2 loads
- map 3 loads
- player A leaves
- map 4 loads
- player A joins
- map 5 loads
- map 6 loads
- player A leaves
- map 7 loads
- map 8 loads

Then the only correct results would be: map 2, 3, 5 and 6.
So I would need to kind of iterate through the resultset and get all maps that happen between a player join and a following player leave, then jump to the next row.

Comment: Pictures? That's not how we roll. And weaponary ain't a word.

Comment: @Strawberry Well I think a picture is better as no picture at all...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the type of SQL flavor you're using, but using general SQL I believe something close to:

```
SELECT *
FROM levelsloaded ll, playerjoins pj, playerleaves pl
WHERE ll.serverId = pj.serverId AND ll.serverId = pl.serverId AND 
      pj.playerId = $IDINQUESTION AND pl.playerId = $IDINQUESTION AND
      ll.date >= pj.date AND ll.date < pl.date;
```

Though I cannot recall if date contains timestamp.

Comment: Fyi, I'm using MySQL. But to the paint, I did not want `15:51:29` and `15:37:10` to be selected... And there can be playerjons/leaves before and after that timestamp, let's say they can occur at'00:00:00' and '23:59:59' aswell for simplicity, then your query would still select the `levelsloaded`? While the intention is to not select them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question properly, if you want the exact inverse of what I wanted, use this as a subquery in a where clause.

Comment: If player joins/player leaves indicates when a  player is on the server. The select statement I revealed would grab all instances of loading while the player in question is online.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell, but I have tested the query. And it also picks them when a player is not online. What your query does is: It picks every level load since the first time the player joined the server, and the last time he left the server. But he can join/leave multiple times, I think you've forgotten that :(

Comment: Apologies. Is there no way to have a sessionId? A sessionId will be a good way to link unique pjs and pls.

Comment: The logfiles from which the playerjoins/playerleaves come unfortunately do not have a sessionId or anything. Do you think that a SQL query, of what I want, is possible at all? Or should I look into providing the neccessary data on the other end (which will not be easy either).

Comment: I have no way to prove it's impossible, but it's very unlikely without some form of sessionId to my knowledge. I'm sorry I can't offer more.